# Can turrets be made/found friendly?

Tags: space-hulk-deathwing

I just started playing Space Hulk: Deathwing and one of the highest damage dealers that have appeared so far are some of the stationary turrets located throughout the maps. So far, I've only found them in two states; active and hostile towards me or deactivated but, if reactivated, will be hostile towards me.

I'm able to destroy/disable them or hack them and control them manually to take advantage of their damage output but this takes time and I generally prefer my assault cannon and power fist to risking something going south while I wait for the progress bar (as happened before to my poor apothecary).

My question is: **Is it possible to either find a turret that is friendly towards you or hack them to make them friendly?** I would find automated turret support to be very helpful in many situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot. They are hostile to you whenever they are on, unless you take control of them and shoot at creatures through the camera.

And when you do that they instantly know exactly where you are and come for you in a horde.

There have been many patches since the game came out. Making hacked turrets friendly is something they should have done a long time ago. The fact they have not done so from some bizarre stubborn sentiment is frustrating as hell.